# Difference between tee command and tee.c

Tags: c, linux, system

I am currently implementing the 'tee' command with C on Ubuntu 20.04 Linux. However, I have noticed a slight difference in the output.

I first test the tee command with

```
ls -l | tee test.txt
```

Here is the output.

[image]

Note: These files are from the Online Source Code for The Linux Programming Interface: https://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/all_files_by_chapter.html

Now, I would like to implement the 'tee' command using the code from this repository:  https://github.com/rmascarenhas/lpi/blob/master/chap04/tee.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE /* getopt function */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef BUF_SIZ
#define BUF_SIZ 1024
#endif

#ifndef MAX_OUT_FILES
#define MAX_OUT_FILES 128
#endif

typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } Bool;
void helpAndLeave(const char *progname, int status);
void failure(const char *fCall);
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int opt;
  Bool append = FALSE;
  int fd, flags;
  int fds[MAX_OUT_FILES];
  mode_t mode;
  char buf[BUF_SIZ + 1];
  ssize_t numRead;
  int i, numFiles = 0;
  /* Command line arguments parsing */
  opterr = 0;
  while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "+a")) != -1) {
    switch(opt) {
      case '?': helpAndLeave(argv[0], EXIT_FAILURE); break;
      case 'h': helpAndLeave(argv[0], EXIT_SUCCESS); break;
      case 'a': append = TRUE;                       break;
    }
  }
  if (optind >= argc) {
    helpAndLeave(argv[0], EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  /* stdin redirection */
  flags = O_CREAT | O_WRONLY;
  mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR; /* rw------- */
  if (append) {
    flags |= O_APPEND;
  } else {
    flags |= O_TRUNC;
  }
  for (i = optind; i < argc; ++i) {
    fds[i - optind] = fd = open(argv[i], flags, mode);
    if (fd == -1) {
      failure("open");
    }
    ++numFiles;
  }
  while ((numRead = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUF_SIZ)) > 0) {
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, numRead) != numRead) {
      failure("write");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < numFiles; ++i) {
      if (write(fds[i], buf, numRead) != numRead) {
        failure("write");
      }
    }
  }
  if (numRead == -1) {
    failure("read");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < numFiles; ++i) {
    if (close(fds[i]) == -1) {
      failure("close");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
void
helpAndLeave(const char *progname, int status) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-a] <file1> <file2> ... <fileN>\n", progname);
  exit(status);
}
void
failure(const char *fCall) {
  perror(fCall);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

After compiling the program, I implement with my own tee program

```
ls -l | ./tee test.txt
```

Here is the output:
[image]

The results are different. **The 'test.txt' file is created and printed to the terminal with a size of 0 bytes.** I have also refered other repositories and made modifications to the 'tee.c' program, but the outcome remains the same - 'test.txt' also appears in the terminal.

Therefore, I would like to inquire why the 'tee.c' program produces a different output compared to the 'tee' command .

Thank for your help.

Comment: It's probably a timing issue.  If the `tee` command (not ʼinstruction’) gets to create its output file before `ls` reads the directory, the filename will appear.  The bigger the directory, the more likely the output the filename will appear.

Comment: If you're on Linux your `tee(1)` is probably the GNU coreutils version; see its source at https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tee.c

Comment: You are looking at the results of the `tee` command (either version) before it has finished working. The results will be inconsistent. Check it like this: `ls -l | tee test.txt ; ls -l test.txt`.

Comment: And did you delete the test.txt file between runs of the different `tee` versions?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I would try to test on smaller directory. Thank for your help!

Comment: @Shawn Yes! I have deleted the test.txt before running different tee version. Thank for your reference about tee(1). I will see it!

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thank for your answer. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

The additional files `tee` and `test.txt` being included in the output are because:

1. `tee` is the executable file generated when you compile up tee.c. When you are using the command `tee`, it uses the file `/usr/bin/tee`, so this does not appear.
2. Typically, utilities like `tee` will create their files in `/usr/tmp` and then move them to their destination as the final action before terminating. This is why it doesn't appear when using the command `tee`. In `tee.c`, the file will be created based on the current directory, so if the command argument is just `test.txt` then this will be created there before the contents of the directory are read.

Comment: Can you give any justification for your claim the `tee` writes to `/usr/tmp`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I can't give you a book reference, but IIRC there is a book (ca 1984) that set standards for Unix (then) utilities. One of these was that output files are created using tmpfile(3) and then link(2) is used as the last action on completion to 'move' it to the right place, with an unlink(2) to remove the entry in the temporary directory. I think the evidence from the OP's question suggests that this is still going on, but I haven't looked at the source for tee.

Comment: I'd love more info. Trying to `link()` from `/usr/tmp` to another mounted file system won't work. These days, with monolithic file systems, it is less likely to be a problem, but in 1984, it would have been a considerable problem. Consequently, the code would have to create the temporary file on the same file system as the output file, and the easiest way to do that is to create it in the same directory as the file.  One book you might be thinking of is  Brian W Kernighan, Rob Pike [The Unix Programming Environment](https://www.amazon.com/dp/013937681X) Nov 1983. But it doesn't have that rule.